# Android get Index 1 out of range on parse json format

Tags: android

i'm trying to parse this below json format such as:

```
[
    [
        {
            "mobileNumber":"<Censored>","contactUserId":"17",
            "userEwallets":
            [
                {"accountNumber":"<Censored>"},
                {"accountNumber":"<Censored>"},
                {"accountNumber":"<Censored>"}
            ]
        }
    ]
,
    [
        {
            "mobileNumber":"<Censored>","contactUserId":"1",
            "userEwallets":
            [
                {"accountNumber":"<Censored>"}
            ]
        }
    ]
]
```

for parsing second json array of that as

```
[
    {
        "mobileNumber":"<Censored>",
        "contactUserId":"1",
        "userEwallets":
        [
            {"accountNumber":"<Censored>"}
        ]
    }
]
```

i get this error:

```
Index 1 out of range [0..1)
```

from below code my code can only parse the first array of that, for second array i get exception when i try to get `mobileNumber` of second json array object

```
for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
    try {
        JSONArray   jsonArray    = response.getJSONArray(i);
        final String mobileNumber  = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("mobileNumber");
        final String contactUserId = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("contactUserId");
        final String userEwallets  = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("userEwallets");

        Log.e("MobileNumber ", mobileNumber);

        JSONArray ewallets = new JSONArray(userEwallets);
        for (int j = 0; j < ewallets.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject   ewalletObject        = ewallets.getJSONObject(j);
            final String accountNumber = ewalletObject.getString("accountNumber");

            Log.e("accountNumber ", accountNumber);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: which line is triggering the error?

Comment: Does your response.length actually match the number of elements in the array? Your should validate your own data and confirm if it matches the datamodel that you're expecting. Based on what I'm seeing, i doubt they match.

Comment: @JoxTraex yes, i get error in `final String mobileNumber  = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("mobileNumber");` for parse second array

Comment: @Lino for this line `final String mobileNumber  = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("mobileNumber");` of second array

Comment: @JoxTraex `response.length()` reruen 2

Comment: You should not post real information in your post. I have censored all the possibly sensitive information.

Comment: Also you should protect your code more.. don't assume things don't return null!!!!

Comment: @JoxTraex all data are fake and not real sir

Comment: The structure of the second array is different. You need one more pair of brackets [ ]

Comment: Better safe than sorry Mahdi, i've seen several posts that post sensitive information.. I censored them to make sure that information doesn't get leaked.

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler the second and the first json array are same, but in second array i have a little data for `userEwallets`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this one...

```
 JSONArray response;
        try {
            response = new JSONArray(res);
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                JSONArray insideJSONArray = response.getJSONArray(i);
                JSONObject jsonObject = insideJSONArray.getJSONObject(0);
                String mobileNumber = jsonObject.getString("mobileNumber");
                Log.e("TAG", "mobileNumber: " + mobileNumber);
                String contactUserId = jsonObject.getString("contactUserId");
                Log.e("TAG", "mobileNumber: " + contactUserId);
                JSONArray userEwallets = jsonObject.getJSONArray("userEwallets");
                for (int j = 0; j < userEwallets.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject ewalletObject = userEwallets.getJSONObject(j);
                    final String accountNumber = ewalletObject.getString("accountNumber");
                    Log.e("accountNumber ", accountNumber);

                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Change:

```
final String mobileNumber  = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("mobileNumber");
final String contactUserId = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("contactUserId");
final String userEwallets  = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("userEwallets");
```

to

```
final String mobileNumber  = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("mobileNumber");
final String contactUserId = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("contactUserId");
final String userEwallets  = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("userEwallets");
```